# How to connect tmxlite to cmake SFML project with VCPKG or any other means (Decided)

Tags: cmake, sfml, vcpkg

Decided(Alexander Neumann):

1. In any directory convenient for you, create a file 'Findtmxlite.cmake'
2. Write the paths, they may differ with us.

```
#Findtmxlite.cmake
set(VCPKG_PATH "${USER_PROFILE}/vcpkg")
set(VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/include")
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/lib")

# Set up tmxlite search

# Find path to tmxlite header files
find_path(tmxlite_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES tmxlite/Map.hpp PATHS VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIR)

# Find the tmxlite library
find_library(tmxlite_LIBRARY NAMES tmxlite PATHS VCPKG_LIBRARY_DIR)

# Create an imported target for tmxlite
add_library(tmxlite INTERFACE)

# Specify the path to the tmxlite header files
target_include_directories(tmxlite INTERFACE ${tmxlite_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Link the tmxlite library to the target
target_link_libraries(tmxlite INTERFACE ${tmxlite_LIBRARY})
```

3. Add the following line to the project

```
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "path/to/Findtmxlite.cmake/dir")
```

After these steps you can use tmxlite in your project

```
find_package(tmxlite REQUIRED)
add_executable (tester "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(tester PRIVATE tmxlite)
```

tmxlite developers please help
Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression status
CMake Error at C:/Users/Agenteec/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:843 (_find_package):
By not providing "Findtmxlite.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "tmxlite", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "tmxlite" with any
of the following names:

tmxliteConfig.cmake
tmxlite-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "tmxlite" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"tmxlite_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
"tmxlite" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed. C:/Users/Agenteec/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake 843
Maybe I misspelled the package name.
Vcpkg list:
tmxlite:x64-windows                               1.3.0#1             A lightweight C++14 parsing library for tmx map ..
tmxlite:x86-windows                               1.3.0#1             A lightweight C++14 parsing library for tmx map ..

```
find_package(tmxlite REQUIRED)
add_executable (tester "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(tester PRIVATE tmxlite)
#does not work

set(VCPKG_PATH "${USER_PROFILE}/vcpkg")
set(VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/include")
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/lib")
add_executable (tester "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE ${VCPKG_LIBRARY_DIR}/tmxlite.lib)
#does not work

set(VCPKG_PATH "${USER_PROFILE}/vcpkg")
set(VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/include")
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_DIR "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/lib")
find_package(tmxlite REQUIRED HINTS "${VCPKG_PATH}/installed/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}")
add_executable (tester "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE tmxlite)
#does not work
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we maintain question and answer posts independently, and do NOT put a solution into a question post. Please, revert your last edit of the question post. If you think that your code of Find script could help future visitors, then you may write an **answer** post. On Stack Overflow it is perfectly acceptable for a question to have several answer posts, which describe different solutions or different aspects of a single solution. Also, it is perfectly acceptable to answer you own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own `Find<Module>.cmake` for `tmxlite` since it neither install pkg-config files nor cmake files.

In the `Find<Module>.cmake` you need to do the following:

- search for the header directory via `find_file`/`find_path`
- search for the (release/debug) library via `find_library`
- (if applicable) `find_package` other dependencies
- define an imported target and use the above to set it up.
- link the defined imported target to your target

(and no you don't need any vcpkg specific hacks here.)